# Keyerror when handling the EventOFPFlowStatsReply message in the Ryu Controller

Tags: python, sdn, openflow, ryu

I'm trying to get the requested FlowStat information in [Simple_monitor_13](https://github.com/faucetsdn/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_monitor_13.py) (Ryu SDN Controller), but when run with a simple mininet topology and "pingall", the application keeps reporting Keyerrors coming from very basic Match Fields like Ipv4_src, eth_type. Did I misunderstand how this event works?  And how can this request be fulfilled?

```
for stat in sorted([flow for flow in body if (flow.priority == 1)], key=lambda flow: 
            (flow.match['in_port'], flow.match['eth_dst'],flow.match['ipv4_src'],flow.match['ipv4_dst'],flow.match['ip_proto'])):
            flow_stat['table_id']= stat.table_id
            flow_stat['priority'] = stat.priority
            flow_stat['in_port'] = stat.match['in_port']
            flow_stat['ip_proto'] = stat.match['ip_proto']
            flow_stat['ipv4_src'] = stat.match['ipv4_src']
            flow_stat['ipv4_dst'] = stat.match['ipv4_dst']
```

```
     File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ryu\base\app_manager.py", line 290, in _event_loop
        handler(ev)
      File "E:\SDN_ML_Anaconda\ryu\ryu\app\simple_monitor_13_fetch.py", line 91, in _flow_stats_reply_handler
        for stat in sorted([flow for flow in body if (flow.priority == 1)], key=lambda flow:
      File "E:\SDN_ML_Anaconda\ryu\ryu\app\simple_monitor_13_fetch.py", line 92, in <lambda>
        (flow.match['in_port'], flow.match['eth_dst'],flow.match['ipv4_src'],flow.match['ipv4_dst'],flow.match['ip_proto'])):
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ryu\ofproto\ofproto_v1_3_parser.py", line 904, in __getitem__
        return dict(self._fields2)[key]
    KeyError: 'ipv4_src'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FlowStatsReply

A FlowStatsReply contains statistics for each flow installed on the switch. Since flows do not have dedicated unique identifiers, they are instead identified by their match fields. If a flow rule does not match on a certain header field, its corresponding flow entry in the FlowStatsReply won't contain that field either.

### Matches in SimpleMonitor13

If you look at [SimpleSwitch13](https://github.com/faucetsdn/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py), which SimpleMonitor13 inherits from, you will find that the controller installs flows in its `_packet_in_handler` with the following match:

```python
 match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst, eth_src=src)
```

Therefore, the FlowStatsReply in SimpleMonitor13 will only contain the fields `in_port`, `eth_dst` and `eth_src`, but not `ipv4_src` or `eth_type`.